# Invariant Violation: ViewPagerAndroid has been removed from React Native. Expo v35 to v39 Migration

Tags: react-native, expo

Tried most of the solutions and even [updated all the packages](https://medium.com/@jh3y/how-to-update-all-npm-packages-in-your-project-at-once-17a8981860ea) but none of them is working for me.

Touching this project after a while so was migrating from

**React Native Expo v35 to v39.**

---

### Error Stack Trace:

[image: Error Stack Trace]

My list of packages:

package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/react-components": "^3.0.1",
    "@apollo/react-hoc": "^3.1.1",
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "^3.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "~1.12.0",
    "@react-native-community/viewpager": "^4.1.6",
    "apollo-boost": "^0.4.4",
    "apollo-fetch": "^0.7.0",
    "apollo-link": "^1.2.13",
    "apollo-link-context": "^1.0.19",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "expo": "^39.0.3",
    "expo-facebook": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-google-app-auth": "^8.0.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~9.1.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.7.2",
    "graphql": "^14.4.2",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-apollo": "^3.1.3",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-aws3": "^0.0.9",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-material-ripple": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.6.0",
    "react-native-multiple-select": "^0.5.3",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^6.3.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.10.1",
    "react-native-status-bar-height": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.2",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^1.4.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.7.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^1.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@graphql-codegen/introspection": "^1.12.2",
    "@types/react": "~16.9.35",
    "@types/react-native": "~0.63.2",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^8.3.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-environment-enzyme": "^7.1.1",
    "jest-enzyme": "^7.1.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3",
    "typescript": "~3.9.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Based on what I read, it's some package that is causing this issue.

Can someone please help me find the package based on the Trace Stack?
I was unable to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Package Name:** `react-navigation`.

**How to search:**
Search for `ViewPagerAndroid` in your VS Code and don't exclude `node_modules`.

**What you need to replace?**

`import {ViewPagerAndroid} from 'react-native'`

with

`import ViewPagerAndroid from '@react-native-community/viewpager'`

---

**NOTE:**
You will need to add `@react-native-community/viewpager` package

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue, I've searched for all the names with ViewPagerAndroid and replaced the import with 'react-native-pager-view' as '@react-native-community/viewpager' has been depreciated but it's still showing the same error. I also tried deleting node_modules and installing them again but still unfixed. Did anyone solve the issue?

Comment: Didn't this solve your issue?